# How to fit a set of curves having some free and some shared parameters?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

## The problem

I have a data set with 1 dependent and $N$ independent variables $x_1,\dots ,x_N$ (all real numbers), and need to fit a (nonlinear) function/curve
$$
f_i(x_i; p_1,\dots ,p_{k_F}, r_1, \dots, r_{k_S})
$$
to each independent variable $x_i$. The curves depend on two kinds of parameters: the parameters $p_1,\dots ,p_{k_F}$ are free to vary from one curve to the other, whereas the parameters $r_1, \dots ,r_{k_S}$ must be shared among the curves (but their optimal values are not known *a priori*). The goal is to find the point $\langle p_1,\dots ,p_{k_F},r_1, \dots ,r_{k_S}\rangle$ in the parameter space that minimizes an objective function (in my specific application, this can be e.g. the cumulative sum of squared residuals $y_i - f_i(x_i)$ across all the $N$ curves, where $y_i$ is the empirical value of the dependent variable in the data set).

## The main question

Is there a generally accepted optimal strategy for solving such an optimization problem, where some parameters are free to vary but others must have the same value across curves?

## What I've tried so far

This is not my field of specialism, but I have toyed with some ideas. The best I've been able to come up with so far is the following procedure:

1. Define sets of values that the shared parameters $r_1, \dots ,r_{k_S}$ can assume.
2. Loop over these sets: for each combination of shared parameter values, find the best-fitting free parameters $p_1, \dots ,p_{k_F}$ using some off-the-shelf method such as nonlinear least squares. Record the value of the objective function and said best-fitting free parameters.
3. Having looped through the shared parameter value sets, return the combination of $r_1, \dots ,r_{k_S}$ and $p_1, \dots ,p_{r_F}$ that gave the best fit.

This method works, but it has the obvious drawback that it doesn't scale well as the number of shared parameters $k_S$ increases. Furthermore, it is not always clear how the value sets to be probed in the loops ought to be defined (i.e. how to set the value range endpoints and resolution). I also find it problematic (though can't quite articulate why) that the shared parameters are treated differently from the free ones, i.e. the shared parameter values are searched from finite, *ad hoc* defined sets, whereas the free parameters are allowed to vary to floating-point precision (depending on what sort of fitting algorithm is used to fit the free parameters, of course).

The procedure can be refined a bit by embedding it in a further loop that makes the parameter value ranges successively smaller with each iteration, thereby kind of "zooming in" on the optimal parameter value combination. But this is just an embellishment.

## The other question

In case the above procedure is actually the best way of tackling the problem (which I very much doubt), does it have a name?

Comment: Do you have any preferred statistical software or programming language?

Comment: @JamesPhillips R would be ideal, or anything that ports easily to R.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility that should scale well is to: A) Independently fit each data set, then B) Determine the mean (or median) value of the independently fitted values for what should be the shared parameter, and finally C) re-fit the individual data sets using the mean value as a constant that is not fitted. Note that if the individual data sets have different numbers of data points the mean value  from step B will effectively be weighted toward the data sets with the most data, if this is not desired then a weighted mean should be used with the weighting dependent on the number of data points per data set. This process should be easily automated.